# Is it possible to have Navlink activeClassName for more than one url? [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I want Cabinet section to be active not only for /cabinet/login url, but also for /cabinet/signup and /cabinet/orders. Here is my code for App and MainNavigation Components.

App.js

```
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Root>
          <Route path='/' exact component={ Home } />
          <Route path='/cabinet/:type' component={ Cabinet } />
          <Route path='/catalog' component={ Catalog } />
          <Route path='/company' component={ Company } />
          <Route path='/contacts' component={ Contacts } />
        </Root>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

MainNavigation.js

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul className="navigation">
        <li style={{height: '20%'}}>
            <NavLink to={"/"} activeClassName="active1" exact>Главная</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li style={{height: '20%'}}>
            <NavLink to={"/cabinet/login"} activeClassName="active2">Кабинет</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li style={{height: '20%'}}>
            <NavLink to={"/catalog"} activeClassName="active2">Каталог</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li style={{height: '20%'}}>
            <NavLink to={"/company"} activeClassName="active3">Компания</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li style={{height: '20%'}}>
            <NavLink to={"/contacts"} activeClassName="active3">Контакты</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Is it possible to have Navlink activeClassName for more than one url?